# Display 404 error when a certain URL is accessed using a specific sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have two sub-domains that point to the exact same files. I use server-side code to control the styling/images. I want a particular page to be accessible to only one of the sub-domains. How can I accomplish this using RewriteRules?

I have different domains set up testing purposes, but they all start with either `http://MICROSOFT` or `http://APPLE`. I only want the page to be displayed if accessing the site by http://MICROSOFT.somethingelse.com/ http://MICROSOFT.another.sub.sub.domain/, but not http://APPLE.com or anything else with APPLE in the hostname.

Going to http://microsoft.anythinghere/special-sub-directory/ will display the page as expected but going to http://apple.anythinghere/special-sub-directory/ will show a 404 error.

How can this code be modified to work like I need it to?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^http://apple\.[A-z0-9]+/special-sub-directory/?$ - [R=404]
</IfModule>
```

Please note, it's a WordPress site, so it has to work with the following rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` does not get the protocol and host name. What you need is an extra [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apple\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^special-sub-directory/?$ - [R=404]
```

---

These are the rules that worked on my development machine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^special-sub-directory/?$ - [R=404]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

- They were placed inside `/.htaccess`
- Accessing `http://localhost/special-sub-directory/` produced 404 error
- Accessing `http://127.0.0.1/special-sub-directory/` displayed correct page
- The other rules worked

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried out your code, but it looks like the WordPress .htaccess rules are causing it not to work. Please see my update above. (note that I've tried inserting your code before and after the WordPress code)

Comment: Hmmm. I'm wondering if the problem is that the directory doesn't exist? The directory is actually just a URL created from WordPress's "Page".

Comment: Removing leading slash should fix the issue. The directory does not have to be there physically. I made the trailing `/` required... change to `/?$` to make it optional.

Comment: I tried copying/pasting your updated code and overwriting mine (then changed localhost to apple\.), but it's still showing the page and not a 404 when accessing the URI under apple.

Comment: I just have a local dev URL set up using MAMP, so it isn't accessible over the net. The actual URL I'm using is http://apple.jenssite.dev/products/.

Comment: Then trailing `/` should be removed. If  `apple.jenssite.dev/products/` is also a valid URL then make it optional instead. See revised code.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm wondering if it's working, but the R=404 isn't being picked up by WordPress, so it never shows the File Not Found error? Any other ideas?

Comment: Yep, just confirmed it's WordPress. I changed the - to http://cnn.com and changed R=404 to L,NC and it directed me to CNN.

Comment: It's crazy cause even with the L, WordPress is still sending me to the page when I try setting it to /404.html

Comment: Can't say what is going on. You should enable [mod_rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and inspect apache error log to see whats going on. You're on your own on this, sorry.